# wget process doesn't stop when php cron ends

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

I'm running my cron using:

```
 $command = 'wget -qO- --timeout=0 --tries=1 my_url &';
 $descriptorspec = array(
   0 = > array('pipe', 'w'), // stdin
   1 = > array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
   2 = > array('pipe', 'w') // stderr
 );
 $proc = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
 proc_close($proc);
```

The reason I have to use timeout=0 is that range of time the cron will run vary from seconds to even couple hours. However I noticed that if cron takes longer than couple of minutes, If I run it above way, it keeps hanging in process tree (even when job is done, so cron finished it task). I tried to force it to stop by sending:

```
header("Connection: close"); 
ob_end_flush(); 
ob_flush(); 
flush();
```

What i want to achieve is to be able to know exactly when process finished, so I can determine whether it stopped because it did it work or because there was some sort of error.

Each cron look similar to:

```
session_write_close(); 
ignore_user_abort(1);
.... do_the_job .... 
header("Connection: close"); 
ob_end_flush(); 
ob_flush(); 
flush();
exit();
```

How can i force wget to die? I would appreciate any tips in that matter. I also tried curl without luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I was able to overcome problem by running it with command:

```
php5 index.php --uri=controller/method/var1/var2
```

for Kohana files, and

```
php5 file_path/file_name.php
```

for other php files. If i had to run file from different server this solution wouldn't work.